# Скачать Oracle

Tags: oracle

Не могу зарегистрироваться на официальном сайте Oracle (www.oracle.com), а также скачать Oracle Express Edition или любое другое ПО. Ошибка:

> System error. Please re-try youraction. If you continue to get thiserror, please contact theAdministrator.

Что это такое, как быть? Где можно скачать Oracle Express Edition?

Answer (score 1):

Бесплатные продукты Oracle можно скачать с официального сайта, в частности Database EE 11 можно скачать по [ссылке](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen) , но для этого необходимо пройти бесплатную регистрацию. Если не получается зарегистрироваться (возникает ошибка на каком-либо этапе) есть вариант что ошибка где-то на этапе выполнения одного из скриптов браузером - советую попробовать регистрацию в разных браузерах.

Comment: есть такой супер браузер google-chrome,он переводит англоязычные сайты,и не только..

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой глюк, попробуйте другой браузер, ослом все качается на ура.

Answer (score 0):

Такое происходит в Opera. Попробуй Firefox'ом или может быть каким другим браузером. Зарегистрироваться может кто угодно и скачать, следовательно, тоже.